# Is it possible to make a Turing Machine that accepts the language $\{\alpha\alpha\alpha | \alpha \in \{a, b\}^∗\}$?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm having a lot of problems trying to make a Turing Machine that accept that language, is it even possible to make it? and if so, how can I proceed to make the Turing Machine?

Comment: Can you write a program in your favorite programming language that accepts this language? If so, a Turing machine can do that as well.

Comment: Yes, I just calculate the length of $\alpha\alpha\alpha$, and then divide it by 3 and see if the tree are the same. So its possible. But how can I make the Turing Machine that accepts it?

Comment: You can implement the very same algorithm on a Turing machine. It won’t be pretty, but it can be done. There are also other approaches which lend themselves more easily to implementation on a Turing machine. You can guess where the second and third copy start, then verify your guess. (Here “guess” means that you’ll try all possibilities.) Whatever you do, you have to sweat. Nobody is going to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a particularly simple algorithm for the slightly simpler language $\{\alpha\alpha \mid \alpha \in \{a,b\}^*\}$; a similar approach works in your case.

The Turing machine starts by checking whether the input is empty (if so, accept) and whether it has even length (otherwise, reject). Next, we are going to find the midpoint of the input. The idea is to put a "chip" on each end of the input, and at each step, advance each chip toward the middle, until the two chips coincide. If done correctly, we can mark the middle of the input, which is the starting point of the second copy of $\alpha$. All that remains to be done is to check that the first half of the input is identical to the second half, which can be done using a simple iteration.

Comment: Well, it's easy to find the midpoint of $\alpha\alpha$ and then check if they are the same, but in the case of $\alpha\alpha\alpha$ you can't use the idea of a midpoint.

Comment: The same way you find a midpoint, you can find the 1/3-point and the 2/3-point. You just have to be slightly creative.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint or something?

Comment: I gave you a huge hint by spelling out what to do in a very similar case. You’ll have to sweat it.